# QBMS refund The field CreditCardTransID is invalid

Tags: xml, coldfusion-9, quickbooks, qbxml

I am using QBMS for my payment
https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

i am facing the issue with refund api. CustomerCreditCardTxnVoidOrRefundRq
it always give me error:
The field CreditCardTransID is invalid.

here is how my request looks like

```
<CustomerCreditCardTxnVoidOrRefundRq>
        <TransRequestID>#attributes.transID#</TransRequestID>
        <CreditCardTransID>#attributes.authID#</CreditCardTransID>
        <Amount>#attributes.amount#</Amount>
        <ForceRefund>true</ForceRefund>
</CustomerCreditCardTxnVoidOrRefundRq>
```

But i am mapping this field with the response i receive when that payment is made through
CustomerCreditCardChargeRq

```
<CustomerCreditCardChargeRs statusCode="INTTYPE" statusSeverity="STRTYPE" statusMessage="STRTYPE">
        <CreditCardTransID >STRTYPE</CreditCardTransID> <!-- optional -->
        <AuthorizationCode >STRTYPE</AuthorizationCode> <!-- optional -->
        <!-- AVSStreet may have one of the following values: Pass, Fail, NotAvailable -->
        <AVSStreet >ENUMTYPE</AVSStreet> <!-- optional -->
        <!-- AVSZip may have one of the following values: Pass, Fail, NotAvailable -->
        <AVSZip >ENUMTYPE</AVSZip> <!-- optional -->
        <!-- CardSecurityCodeMatch may have one of the following values: Pass, Fail, NotAvailable -->
        <CardSecurityCodeMatch >ENUMTYPE</CardSecurityCodeMatch> <!-- optional -->
        <MerchantAccountNumber >STRTYPE</MerchantAccountNumber> <!-- optional -->
        <ReconBatchID >STRTYPE</ReconBatchID> <!-- optional -->
        <PaymentGroupingCode >INTTYPE</PaymentGroupingCode> <!-- optional -->
        <!-- PaymentStatus may have one of the following values: Unknown, Completed -->
        <PaymentStatus >ENUMTYPE</PaymentStatus> <!-- optional -->
        <TxnAuthorizationTime >DATETIMETYPE</TxnAuthorizationTime> <!-- optional -->
        <TxnAuthorizationStamp >INTTYPE</TxnAuthorizationStamp> <!-- optional -->
        <ClientTransID >STRTYPE</ClientTransID> <!-- optional -->
</CustomerCreditCardChargeRs>
```

any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: is there any 1 who can answer this about quickbook MS refund?

Comment: I would bet $100 that you're not actually sending the correct credit card transaction ID. But since you didn't post the actual transaction ID or XML request/response you got from Intuit, no one is really going to be able to help you.